# Django getting ERROR: Invalid syntax for time type

Tags: django

When I try to send messages to a temporary email address, it arrives there but does not go into the django database.

**view.py**

```
def about(req):
    form = MessangeForm()
    if req.method == "POST":
        form = MessangeForm(req.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data.get('title')
            body = form.cleaned_data.get('body')
            try:
                send_mail(subject, body, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, ["nakkosikni@gufum.com"], fail_silently=False)
                form.save()
            except Exception as err:
                print(str(err))
            return redirect('index')

    return render(req, "about.html", {"form": form})
```

**models.py**

```
class Messange(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name='Subject', max_length=250, null=True, blank=True )
    body = models.TextField(verbose_name='Body')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'(self.body)'
```

**forms.py**

```
class MessangeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Messange
        fields = ["title", "body"]
        widgets = {
            "body": forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

**HTML Template**

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
  <h1>About</h1>
<!-- <p>{{ user.username }} </p>  -->
<form method="POST" >
   {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form|crispy }}
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Add Comment</button>
  </form>

{% endblock %}
```

When I click on submit button I get this error.

```
[07/Dec/2022 22:19:08] "GET /about HTTP/1.1" 200 2437 ОШИБКА: неверный синтаксис для типа time: "иавипачич" LINE 1: ...service_messange" ("title", "body") VALUES ('сч', 'иавипачич... ^
[07/Dec/2022 22:19:26] "POST /about HTTP/1.1" 302 0 [07/Dec/2022 22:19:26] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 226
```

Translated:

```
[07/Dec/2022 22:19:08] "GET /about HTTP/1.1" 200 2437 ERROR: Invalid syntax for time type: "avipacich" LINE 1: ...service_messange" ("title", "body") VALUES ('sch', 'iawipacich... ^
```

[image: Error image]

I don't understand what needs to be changed there.

Comment: I do not see the error in the code you show.  Please add the HTML template where the form is, and the FULL traceback, not just the line with the error.

Comment: To add code, do I need to change my code or create a new request? It's just that it's not entirely clear to me how to place codes.

Comment: You can just edit the question.  I just don't see in what you show where the error comes from.  Your HTML looks fine.  The error indicates something about time, but I see nothing in what you show about time.  Can you copy and paste your *full* trace.  I only see the two lines, one with the time error, the other looks like the POST is fine too.

Comment: I still don't see the error, but try putting `form.save()` right after `if form.is_valid()` instead of in the `try ... except` block, and see what error shows up, and if something is saved in the database.

Comment: The error is the same, I made a screen and uploaded it to the site.

Comment: Did you by any chance have a Date field in your `Messange` class, then delete it, and forget to run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`?  I'm sorry, I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: That's right, you sent me an idea, I did a timefile migration, in the body, but I need a text file, now I did the migration again and everything worked thanks.

Comment: So happy you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

The `DataError` exception shown in the image is a django [database exception](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/exceptions/#database-exceptions).  The cause of the error in this case was not due to any problems in the code shown, rather a change in the model before the database migrations were run.  The `body` field of the class `Mesange` was changed from a date to a `CharField`, but the migrations were not run, leading to the error.  The database was simply looking for a date and/or time, but was receiving a `CharField`.

The solution was simply to run

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```